# Repeating inexact alarms once a week

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I need to do a task every week in my app and it doesn't really care the precision, so I'm thinking to use setInexactRepeating() but I can't find any constant for a week delay. From documentation it seems that  you can use only defined constants. I could use a simpler setRepeating() but I don't want to set exact alarm for api < 19. How can I do? Can I only set the timer to INTERVAL_DAY?

Comment: As mentioned by Egor N, the constants are simply for convenience and represent time periods in milliseconds. If you look at `setInexactRepeating(...)` the `intervalMillis` parameter is a `long` value - use anything you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `INTERVAL_DAY` constant you'll see:

```
public static final long INTERVAL_DAY = 86400000L;
```

It is 86,400,000 milliseconds which is equal to 1 day. It means, that you can use your own value in milliseconds in the `setInexactRepeating` method. A week would be `INTERVAL_DAY * 7`.

Comment: Ok, but maybe I don't understand docs. It says you can use *only* the predefined constant, so I thought that I couldn't define my own constant, isn't it?

Comment: You can use whatever value you want, but: "Prior to API 19, if this is one of INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_HALF_DAY, or INTERVAL_DAY then the alarm will be phase-aligned with other alarms to reduce the number of wakeups. Otherwise, the alarm will be set as though the application had called setRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent). As of API 19, all repeating alarms will be inexact and subject to batching with other alarms regardless of their stated repeat interval."